# iOS BoxSDK getting unrecognized selector for imageFromBoxSDKResourcesBundleWithName

Tags: ios, box-api

`FolderPicker-SampleApp` works great,but when I tried to run it in my code I got a crash when

```
[BoxFolderPickerViewController viewDidLoad]
```

calls

```
[UIImage imageFromBoxSDKResourcesBundleWithName:]
```

for the first time (line 213)

I have `-ObjC` set and even `-all_load` and I even tried adding `-all_load` to the BoxSDK xcode project.

Xcode itself recognize the class category method but for some reason it was lost in linking

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved - I copied the -ObjC (and -all_load) in "Build Settings" "Other Linker Flags" row from the "Project" column to the "Target" column